# Getting Sign Here URL by API which is sent in email

Tags: docusignapi

We are using docusign API to ask signer for signature via Email. We analysed the URL and found that it has two query parameters('a' and 'er'). Is there a way to get these two param pragmatically using API which can be used to generate runtime URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can generate direct URLs to use for sending and signing documents through DocuSign, but you don't grab it from the request emails that you are talking about - it's a completely separate process.  What you want is a feature in the DocuSign platform known as **Embedding**.

With Embedding you can generated authenticated URL "tokens" that can be used only once and they must be used before they expire in 5 mins and you have to generate a new one.  To generate a URL for a given recipient, though, you need to add them to the envelope in a slightly different way.  You need to set their **clientUserId** property along with their email and name, and then refer to that same clientUserId, email, name combination when requesting a signing URL for them.

For instance, if you were creating an envelope from a template and wanted to use Embedding to generate a signing URL then you could use the following request body to create the envelope:

```
{
"accountId": "221765",
"emailSubject": "Hello World!",
"emailBlurb": "This comes from PHP",
"templateId": "9347C7AF-7EEE-4CEC-BA19-2734986F5501",
"templateRoles": [
    {
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "clientUserId": "1001",
        "roleName": "Signer1",
        "tabs": {
            "textTabs": [
                {
                    "tabLabel": "address",
                    "value": "123 Main St. SF, CA"
                },
                {
                    "tabLabel": "zipCode",
                    "value": "94043"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
],
"status": "sent"
}
```

Then you could use the following request body to generate the signing URL for a given recipient.  Notice how the clientUserId (along with their email and name) matches from when we created the envelope:

```
{
"returnUrl": "http://www.docusign.com/devcenter",
"authenticationMethod": "None",
"email": "test@gmail.com",
"userName": "John Doe",
"clientUserId": "1001"
}
```

The following page from the DocuSign Dev Center has detailed information on how to accomplish this (it's actually quite easy):
http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign

DocuSign also has two fantastic tools to help you test this and start coding it, the API Walkthroughs (which have sample code you copy out of the box, including 3 focused on Embedding functionality) and the API Explorer - which allows you to make any api call without writing a single line of code.

[DocuSign API Walkthroughs](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthroughs)
[DocuSign API Explorer](http://iodocs.docusign.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ergin. We are aware of the Embedded Signing scenario but worried because of need to make REST call to get "token" each time(or multiple times per envelope if not used in 5 min) as we have limited number of REST calls per hour. Anyway your answer is very descriptive and helpful. It has cleared my doubt about time limit of token- Thanks a lot for that. I can not accept your answer for now, until we are very sure that there is not other way than embedded signing. Thanks for very detailed information on Embedded signing though.

Comment: So why not simply request a URL token when your users finally click a button or take some other action instead of generating a token that might expire since they're not ready to sign yet?  Plus are you sure you'd get close to your limits, you do know that you get 1000 calls per hour per account in both demo and in production right?

Comment: Will give it a try, Thanks a lot. I think we will not cross this limit as we are using DocuSign Connect for push events. Which makes only one REST call per envelope at the moment and will become 2 calls per envelope after generating token on an average.

Comment: Ok yeah please give it a try as this should suit your needs well here.  The other thing that's nice is that with Embedding you don't need to wait for any emails to arrive to start signing/sending/etc. so it's quicker envelope access with Embedding...

Comment: Thanks Ergin. We have chosen to move forward with embedded signing. Thanks for your help and code in answer.